# C++ Xlib app results in coredump from KeyCodetoKeySym?

Tags: c++, linux, xlib

I have this application:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //... initialize window
    while (!kill_signal) {
        while (window->HasNextEvent()){
        }
        //...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

class:

```
bool Window::HasNextEvent(){
    XEvent e;
    return this->ProcessEvent(&e);
}

bool Window::ProcessEvent(XEvent* e){
    int ascii = -1;
    bool ret = ParentClass::HasNextWindowEvent(e);
    switch(e->type) {
        case KeyPress:
            ascii = XLookupKeysym(&e->xkey, 0);
            break;
            //...
    }
    return ret;
}
```

parent class:

```
bool ParentClass::HasNextWindowEvent(XEvent* e)
{
    bool ret = false;
    ret = XCheckMaskEvent(mDisplay, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | StructureNotifyMask, e);

    if (!ret && this->isPending() > 0) {
        XSync(mDisplay, true);
    }

    switch(e->type)
    {
        case KeyPress:
            if (XLookupKeysym(&e->xkey, 0) == 0xFF1B)
```

At a certain point in my application I receive this coredump and its always as a result of the call to XLookupKeysym:

```
./run.sh: line 3:   914 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./main
```

I examined the coredump with gdb

```
Core was generated by `./main'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fe7c19a3bc9 in KeyCodetoKeySym (dpy=<optimized out>, keycode=      <optimized out>, col=0)
at KeyBind.c:105
105         XConvertCase(syms[col&~1], &lsym, &usym);
```

My code uses KeyCodetoKeySym through my call to XLookupKeysym in the xlib library. Heres the source code from xlibs KeyBind.c:

```
KeySym
XLookupKeysym(event, col)
register XKeyEvent *event;
int col;
{
    if ((! event->display->keysyms) && (! _XKeyInitialize(event->display)))
        return NoSymbol;
    return KeyCodetoKeySym(event->display, event->keycode, col);
}
```

Is this type of behavior usually a result of a memory leak? Or have I somehow stumbled into a bug in my xlib library.

Comment: There's not enough information to guess.  You might try using a tool such as `valgrind`, which would give better information than stray opinions.

Comment: i added the parent class hopefully for more context? I don't know what other information to provide. Can you elaborate on what information is missing?

Comment: `KeyCodetoKeySym` is part of your code, but you haven't included that function in your question.

Comment: XLookupKeysym if you look at xlib source code is a reference to KeyCodetoKeySym

Comment: i added a snippet of KeyBind.c showing the call to KeyCodetoKeySym